# php-devel package required but is already installed

Tags: php, oci8, phpize

I am running PHP 7.2 and am trying to install oci8

`pecl install oci8` results in a download but it fails when running phpize with the following message:

```
running: phpize
Can't find PHP headers in /opt/remi/php72/root/usr/include/php
The php-devel package is required for use of this command.
ERROR: `phpize' failed
```

Howver, if I try to install php-devel I get a message that it is already installed:

```
Package php-devel-5.4.45-17.el7.remi.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

I have tried several options but cannot get phpize to work. Any help appreciated.

Thanks

### UPDATE

- I did a fresh install of php 7.3 using remi. This installed the php.ini file into the /etc directory
- I installed php73-php-oci8
- I confirmed the php version and module in phpinfo()

With regards Oracle Instant Client, I am not entirely sure what I am doing so here is what I did:

- cd /etc/yum.repos.d
- (a few steps to get packages)
- sudo yum install oracle-instantclient18.3-basic
- sudo yum install oracle-instantclient18.3-devel
- sudo yum install oracle-instantclient18.3-jdbc
- sudo yum install oracle-instantclient18.3-sqlplus
- sudo yum list oracle-instantclient*  ... this confirms the installs

This is as far as I can get. I am not sure how to "include it in the library path". I am not clear on the next step. Please advise

Thank you

Comment: Try`yum install php72-php-devel`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are using the php72 SCL, you need the **php72-php-devel** package.

But, why do you want to build from sources, when nearly all extensions are available ?

```
yum install php72-php-oci8
```

Notice: this package requires the oracle client v18.3 installed, and in the library path.

P.S. indeed, the error message probably need to be fixed.

Comment: Thanks Remi. I followed your instructions and - to my surprise - the system says it is installed. I also see that oracle client v19.3 is installed but despite this if I run function_exists('oci_connect') it is not installed. I have been trying for over a week to connect my php to an oracle database with no luck. Can you direct me to a useful guide or give me some guidance on what to test. I think the php setup must be wrong in my server (it was set up by somebody else). Surely it cannot be this hard to connect to Oracle? Any help appreciated

Comment: @DrBorrow as your question changed surprisingly (but now you revealed the secret;) it may better fit to [dba.se] or [su]. As you still hide your steps that you tried so far I provide general sources for connection oracle with php. First is from php-docs [oci8.installation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/oci8.installation.php), second from oracle [connect-php-72-to-oracle-database-12c-using-oracle-linux-yum-server](https://blogs.oracle.com/linux/connect-php-72-to-oracle-database-12c-using-oracle-linux-yum-server)

Comment: As I said, for now, oci8 uses oracle v18.3 NOT 19.3 (which will be used in a near future)

Comment: Thanks Remi - I have tried to follow your guidance. Please see update in the question. I think I am almost there.

Comment: @RemiCollet you may have seen this, but if not, note the IC 19.3 package changes: https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/oracle-instant-client-19c-for-linux-is-available

Comment: @DrBorrow when in doubt, read the [Instant Client installation instructions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html#ic_x64_inst) which show how to run ldconfig to "include it in the library path"  (Note this step won't be needed for IC 19.3)

Comment: WOOOHOO! It is working! Thank you @RemiCollet and ChristopherJones For anybody following this question, the final step was 'sudo sh -c "echo /opt/oracle/instantclient_18_3 > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient.conf"'

Comment: @ChristopherJones indeed, I'm aware of the need to update to 19.3, which I plan soon.